# Manifest help required

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mysmartftp"
android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <application
  android:allowBackup="true"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
 <activity
  android:name="com.mysmartftp.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.mysmartftp.MainActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
  <activity
  android:name=".splash.MainActivity"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
 <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried to link main activity file of the FTP with splash file but it throws and error of . how do I fix it ? Also My first main screen is user name password and when it logs in it is supposed to give upload and download option but when I press ok button it doesn't do anything. kindly help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change Like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.mysmartftp.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<action android:name="com.mysmartftp.MainActivity" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

should be inside an activity tag like this:

```
 <activity android:name="com.mysmartftp.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

action specified by you is wrong and category can be Launcher/Default or something else depending on your requiremnet.